# How to create range datePicker like in this photo

Tags: flutter

I was learning Flutter and came across this photo [image]

As you can see from the above photo, it shows calendar for June 2020 and July 2020. So, if we scroll down August 2020 should be shown then September 2020 and so on so forth. Also, if we reach December 2020 by scrolling then January 2021 should come in a range. The question is how can I create such calendar, I mean, if we scroll down, the subsequent month should come or we scroll top then precedent month calendar should appear. To acheive that do I need to put datepicker in ListTile? or ...? Also, I want to make each calendar day clickable so that I can mark that clicked day as, for example, birthday.

PLEASE GUYS I REALLY NEED YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at [flutter_rounded_date_picker](https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-rounded-date-picker) or [flutter_date_pickers](https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-date-pickers-without-dialog) and try to make any good of them.